# Trouble Trying to Hide Email From Address List Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, error-handling, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to run a simple command to hide an email account from the address list using PowerShell.  Here is my code so far.

```
cls

$EmployeeEmail = "user@example.com"

#Need to hide the Mailbox from address list
$MethodName = "Hide Email Account"

$username = "staff"
$password = "accounts"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://Exchmbca1.example.local/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $cred

Import-PSSession $Session

Set-Mailbox -Identity $EmployeeEmail -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

However, when I run this command I receive the following error message:

The operation couldn't be performed because object 'user@example.com' couldn't be found on 'servername.example'.

I have tried changing the value of the -Identity I pass to the Set-Mailbox cmdlet with 'DOMAIN\username' as well and I receive the same error.  I know the account exists because I can do a search using Get-ADUser and find the account with the SAMAccountName.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Knowing the AD account exists does not mean the _mailbox_ exists. Can you verify the mailbox exists?

Comment: I just did a Get-Recipient on the same Identity I pass to the Set-Mailbox and I am able to locate the mailbox.

Comment: That tells me something is up with how you are inputting the identity if you can pipe that information successfully that. When you do a `get-mailbox samaccountname` do you get the mailbox back? with those results you can check the other information to see if it matches up with what you were trying to do.

Comment: I successfully find the account using Get-Recipient with the identity, however when I use the Get-Mailbox cmdlet I receive the same error: The operation couldn't be performed because object couldn't be found.

Comment: Note that the ability to use specific cmdlets require membership in certain groups.  You should check to see that the account you are authenticating with is a member of at least Recipient Management.